# NoSuchFileException: --zookeeper kafka gives error in macbook

Tags: apache-kafka

I am trying to create topics called 'inverter'

```
kafka-server-start.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic transactions --create --partitions 3 --replication-factor 1
```

in kafka, but stuck with following error:

```
[2021-12-30 17:14:36,475] ERROR Exiting Kafka due to fatal exception (kafka.Kafka$)
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: --zookeeper
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:92)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:106)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:111)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:219)
        at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:380)
        at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:432)
        at java.base/java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.newInputStream(FileSystemProvider.java:422)
        at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.newInputStream(Files.java:160)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils.loadProps(Utils.java:666)
        at kafka.Kafka$.getPropsFromArgs(Kafka.scala:52)
        at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:86)
        at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)
```

I search in google and found that zookeeper is removed from newest version of kafka.
So I was trying to use create instead of zookeeper but still couldn't pass.
Any hint, idea to get rid of this error?

Do I have to run kafka server in another terminal to make topics?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It appears you've mistyped the command. The options you gave are for `kafka-topics.sh`

The Kafka server start script accepts one *file argument*, the server properties file

The error is saying its parsing your first argument, zookeeper, which is not a file that exists

> found that zookeeper is removed from newest version of kafka

Not completely, yet. KRaft mode is optional as of Kafka 3.0

---

Yes, you need to run Kafka server as a daemon (given `-daemon`), or in another terminal before topics can be made